# How to add padding to Microsoft Word table cells

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to have a spacing between horizonal borders of two adjacent table cells like in this example. I want borders below "Commerce FAculty" and "EBE Faculty" not to touch in order to use horizonal border for grouping. Is this possible?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

**Instructions**

1. Highlight the relevant cells, after making sure that they have no preexisting overlapping border beforehand (e.g. cell-based bottom border).
2. Right click.
3. Select 'Table Properties'.
4. Select 'Borders and Shading'.
5. Apply to 'Paragraph'.
6. Add your desired borders (in this case, bottom border).
7. Click 'OK'.

If you do this but the borders are still connected, you need to specify the necessary cell margins, for either the relevant cells or the whole table.

Example table:[image]

This solution is based on: https://wordribbon.tips.net/T013179_Underlining_Cells_Not_Space_Between_Cells.html

Answer (score 1):

This will probably depend on the Version of Word you are using, but on mine, I am able to select **Table Properties...** with a context sensitive click, then under the **Table** tab choose **Options**, and then under **Options** turn on **Default Cell Spacing** and set it to what you want.

You may have to search for something similar in yours. I am using the Mac version of Word.

Answer (score 0):

Borders always go to the edges of the cells.  Two solutions:

- If you want to use borders, include a narrow dummy column in between that you leave empty.  Within the dummy columns, include the borders where you want them and exclude the ones you don't.  This might require a little extra work manipulating column widths.
- Underscore those headings instead of using a border in that location.  The underscore won't extend beyond the words, which will leave a gap between them.

Comment: I don't want that as then I can't equally space out the columns, that dummy column gets expanded as well

Comment: You could make all the columns equal size and then shrink the dummy columns.  If you use borders, they go to the edges of the column.  Another approach would be to use underscores on those headings rather than a border.  That wouldn't extend beyond the words, so you would have a small gap at the column boundaries.